# How to use Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) and get GPS data in the picture?

Tags: android, gps, photo

Is there a way to get a photo taken with Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) and the stock camera app, which has the GPS location already set in the Exif data?

My app requests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

in the Manifest and also

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

in the code, but the photo I receive doesn't contain the location data. When I take a picture directly with the camera the location information is available in the photo.

EDIT: I forgot to add that I'm using a Nexus 6P to test it and when I use the included Camera app (3.2.045) for the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent I see the "location pin" in the system tray for a second before the camera viewfinder is shown. This led me to believe that there might be a setting or parameter missing that would enable the writing of location information in the picture file.

Comment: @NicholasRaoul: FWIW, the answer is still the same, nearly seven years later.

Comment: That is rather unfortunate, CommonsWare. The fact that we can't reliably get location via the intent even on devices running stock Android (Nokia 2.3 for example) is just concerning. I just hope the world was more ideal than it is now :-<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no single "stock camera app". There are thousands of Android device models. They will ship with hundreds of different "stock camera app" implementations, as most device manufacturers create their own (and, in the case of Samsung, have *many* such camera apps across their fleet). Plus `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will not necessarily use a "stock camera app". Rather it uses whatever the user wants to, which may be a third-party camera app installed from the Play Store or elsewhere.

There is no way for your app to request EXIF location data be added to the photo by the camera app, and there is no requirement for a camera app to include EXIF location data. I am not the least bit surprised at the results you are seeing.

You are welcome to get the location data yourself and, using [an EXIF library](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/31/tale-two-exifinterfaces.html), add that data to the photo, if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'm aware of "no single stock camera app". I forgot to add that I'm using the Nexus 6P and when I start the image capture intent I see the "location pin" in the system tray for a second, before the viewfinder is shown. That led me to think that maybe this specific app is capturing the location data but is not including it in the final file because some setting was missing.

Comment: @MatthiasSchippling: I cannot comment as to why that app would briefly request the location, then not include it in the EXIF output. But, there is no extra that you can include that says "please put location data in EXIF headers". Even if there were, there is no requirement for a camera app to honor that extra. You might peek at the EXIF headers for the photo, see if you have a location, and then handle the missing location as needed (ignore it, get the location and add it yourself, etc.).

Comment: That's what I assumed, I just wanted to make sure that I'm not overlooking something. Thanks again.